# ASP.NET Web Api nightly builds doesn't run on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I get this error message on my server:

> Method 'GetVirtualPath' in type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HostedHttpRoute' from assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
>
> > RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...)

I use Nuget to download the latest nightly build of Microsoft ASP.NET Web Api.
It's seems like a bin/gac problem but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An older version of *System.Web.Http* was installed in the GAC.

```
gacutil /uf system.web.http
```

That fixed it.